# Why does there appear to be a distinct lack of good questions on Christianity Stack recently?

Tags: discussion

Is it just my imagination or are the number of decent questions on Christianity Stack falling off?  All week I've been searching for something I can answer and most of the interesting ones were put on hold and subsequently closed.

As of this Saturday morning (08:30 hours, August 10) Christianity Stack has 11,349 questions in total.  Over the course of the last 10 days, 29 questions appear of which 3 are on hold and 2 have been closed.  I understand why those questions are on hold or have been closed.

Is there any reason for the drop in new questions being asked on Christianity Stack?

Comment: Old stable sites often have decreasing question rates as many of the good questions have already been asked.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. However, isn't this approach somewhat self-defeating inasmuch as there may come a point in time where there are no new good questions left to ask and everyone will simply use Christianity Stack as a reference site?

Comment: If that were to happen it wouldn't be a disaster, no one here earns money from answering new questions or anything like that. And I think there will always be a steady stream of increasingly narrow and obscure questions, though less than there was years ago.

Comment: There are also seasonal factors, with some times of year busier than others. And for a site this size individuals can make a big difference, with some people leaving and others joining.

Comment: Yes, that all makes sense.  Perhaps lots of people are taking their annual vacation at this time of year.  In the meantime, I will keep occupied by trying to come up with some questions myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### As a frustrated review queue worker for the past two years; noise > signal

Our topic attracts a lot of noise.  We do well to remove the noise from our site.
I think stuff like this comes in bursts, but maybe we have peaked and we will be lucky to get better content in the future.  One can only hope.

#### Dupes

They happen. There are a lot of different ways to ask the same question

#### Lazy internet users

The utter lack of even modest research rather screams off the page for a great many questions that arrive here, and the lack of effort put into far too many arriving answers has remained consistent.

#### Trolling

Some people show up at a site that is about Christianity looking for a bun fight, or an argument.  That's what a forum is for, but they dump their trash here.

Comment: Yes, those are all valid points.  I left a "Religion & Spirituality" site that had become toxic because the moderators appeared to encourage trolling and would remove honest questions and answers because participants were allowed to vote off anything they didn't like. Oh, and they appeared to be driven by "political correctness" to the extent that any perceived offence would be taken as grounds to close down an account.

Answer (score 8):

Stellar questions here have no answers.  My personal filter for unanswered [Catholicism questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers,NoAcceptedAnswer&tagMode=Watched&uqlId=1) has 75 in need of answers.  When good questions don't get answered (or the answers stink) then people don't come back to ask more good questions.  So, IMO, the fix for the problem of no good questions is to take the unanswered percentage down a few pegs. When C.SE was in beta, that was one stat that we really excelled at.

Comment: That's helpful - will use the filter for unanswered questions and apply myself to that.

Answer (score -2):

Good questions will come more from new users.  Yet those have to go through the point system and are often blocked early by some bullies here who are apparently afraid of new folks for some reason.  They are illogical and arrogant and enforce rules the way they read them even if others have posted the opposite opinions from them on what should be allowed or blocked.